# which CNN architecture is good for plant leaf disease detection?

Tags: computer-vision, gpu, conv-neural-network, data-science

I'm working on plant disease detection using leave images of a plant. I'll use CNN algorithm for this task. My environment is Windows pc with 2.5 GHz CPu and 4GB ram (NO GPU). Which CNN algorithm will be good for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're much constrained on resources, here are some approaches you might want to try:

- Use (very) small CNN. Consider e.g. [MobileNet](https://github.com/arthurdouillard/keras-mobilenet) or [Effnet](https://github.com/arthurdouillard/keras-effnet). Both can work on mobiles and your PC has somewhat specs of a mobile. In the links you'll find source code and articles that discuss them in detail.
- Use pretrained, state-of-the-art CNN and use transfer learning. *Keras* is very easy on newcomers, which is why I'd recommend checking out its [model zoo](https://modelzoo.co/framework/keras). There are some nice tutorials ([1](https://www.kaggle.com/suniliitb96/tutorial-keras-transfer-learning-with-resnet50), [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-transfer-learning-for-beginners-6c9b8b7143e)) out there that explain how to do that in practice.
- Follow [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/plant-ai-plant-disease-detection-using-convolutional-neural-network-9b58a96f2289) where author uses machine not much more powerful than yours.
- [Benchmark](https://github.com/MarkoArsenovic/DeepLearning_PlantDiseases) of deep learning approaches for the plant disease detection

That being said, you might want to consider using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), which offers free GPU.

Comment: @YidnekachewKibru I am glad you have found it helpful! Can you upvote / accept the answer? That's how this forum works. Cheers!

Comment: sure, sorry I forgot that.